# Program Crash after displaying 2D array from queue

Tags: c++, class, multidimensional-array, crash

My C++ program consists of a class called States that has to hold a "state" of my puzzle which is a 3x3 int array and two other integers. When I declare them in main and print them, they print correctly with correct values, but after putting them into a priority_queue, sorted by one of the ints in the class, and pulling it back out, it has garbage in the array and crashes when it tries to display. I have no clue why it is getting garbage when I put it in and then pull back out, can anyone explain/help?

main.cpp:

```
#include "states.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
priority_queue<States> statesQueue;
int puzzle[3][3];
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
     for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
         puzzle[i][j] = i+j;

States myPuzzle(puzzle);
States myPuzzle2;

myPuzzle.printPuzzle();
myPuzzle2.printPuzzle();
myPuzzle.setFOfN(5);
myPuzzle2.setFOfN(0);

statesQueue.push(myPuzzle);
statesQueue.push(myPuzzle2);

if(statesQueue.empty()==true)
    cout<< "This is empty" <<endl;
else
    cout<< "This is not empty" <<endl;

statesQueue.top().printPuzzle();

system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

States.h:

```
#define STATES_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class States
{
public:

    States ();
    States (int puzzle[][3]);
    ~States();

    int getFOfN() const;
    void setFOfN(int num);

    int getGOfN() const;
    void setGOfN(int num);

    void incGOfN();
    int** getPuzzle() const;

    void printPuzzle() const;

    bool States::operator<(const States& rhs) const
    {
         return (fOfN < rhs.getFOfN());
    }
    States& operator = (const States& rhs)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
            {    
                cout<< i << " " << j << " " << rhs.getPuzzle()[i][j] <<endl;
                puzzleGame[i][j] = rhs.getPuzzle()[i][j];
            }
        }
    }                         


private:
    int** puzzleGame;
    int gOfN;
    int fOfN;
};
#endif
```

States.cpp:

```
#include "states.h"
#include <iostream>

States::States ()
{
puzzleGame = new int*[3];

for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    puzzleGame[i] = new int[3];

puzzleGame[0][0] = 1;
puzzleGame[0][1] = 2;
puzzleGame[0][2] = 3;
puzzleGame[1][0] = 4;
puzzleGame[1][1] = 0;
puzzleGame[1][2] = 5;
puzzleGame[2][0] = 6;
puzzleGame[2][1] = 7;
puzzleGame[2][2] = 8;

}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
States::States (int puzzle[][3])
{
puzzleGame = new int*[3];

for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    puzzleGame[i] = new int[3];

for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        puzzleGame[i][j] = puzzle[i][j];
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
States::~States()
{
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    delete [] puzzleGame[i];
}
delete [] puzzleGame;
puzzleGame = 0;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------      
int States::getFOfN() const
{

return fOfN;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
void States::setFOfN(int num)
{
 fOfN = num;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------      
int States::getGOfN() const
{

return gOfN;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
void States::setGOfN(int num)
{
 gOfN = num;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------      
void States::incGOfN()
{
 gOfN++;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
int** States::getPuzzle() const
{

return puzzleGame;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
void States::printPuzzle() const
{
std::cout<< "+---+---+---+" <<std::endl;
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        if(puzzleGame[i][j]==0)
            std::cout<< "|   ";
        else
            std::cout<< "| " << puzzleGame[i][j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout<< "|" <<std::endl;
std::cout<< "+---+---+---+" <<std::endl;
}
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is what happens everytime it displays:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e2d1.png)

Answer (score 0):

`States` violates the Rule of Three and cannot be safely copied. [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) Glad you asked. Read the link.

In this case, copying `States` results in both the original and the copy pointing at the same `puzzleGame` When one is deleted it takes `puzzleGame` with it and the other is now a walking timebomb just waiting to invoke Undefined Behaviour.

This is a problem because pushing to a queue makes a copy, and that copy could be copied, moved, deleted or whatever else the queue's backing container decides to do to it.

The simple fix is to replace the dynamic `puzzleGame` array in `States` with a static one since the dimensions are known. [`std::array` may be helpful here.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) Less suitable options include using a `std::vector<std::vector<States>>` and implementing assignment and move operators and copy and move constructors that correctly handle `puzzleGame`.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. After much anger trying to get those three implemented correctly, it is working great.